# How to change change variables to 0 if BOTH columns = NA

Tags: r

In the R data frame below, I would like to replace all of the instances where that both columns = NA to both columns = 0

So I would like to change this:

```
Col 1   Col 2
   1       1
   3       2
  NA      NA
   3      NA
  NA       3
  NA      NA
```

and would like the result to be:

```
Col 1   Col 2
   1       1
   3       2
   0       0
   3      NA
  NA       3
   0       0
```

Comment: `df[rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df), ] <- 0`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a logical index with `rowSums` on the logical matrix (`!is.na(df1)` -  which will give `TRUE` values for non-NA and `FALSE` for NA. By doing the `rowSums`, rows that have 0 NAs i.e. all FALSE, will return 0 and others will be greater than 0.  Negating (`!`) the `vector` returns TRUE for 0 values and all others FALSE) and then assign the rows to 0

```
df1[!rowSums(!is.na(df1)),] <- 0
df1
#   Col 1 Col 2
#1     1     1
#2     3     2
#3     0     0
#4     3    NA
#5    NA     3
#6     0     0
```

Or it can be also done in the other way by not negating and comparing with the number of columns

---

Another option is to loop through the columns, check for the NAs with `is.na` and then `Reduce` it to a logical `vector` to assign the rows that are TRUE based on it to 0

```
df1[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df1, is.na)), ] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want the columns explicitly referenced, you can also do

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c(1, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA), col2=c(1, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA))
df[is.na(df$col1) & is.na(df$col2), ] <- 0
df
##  col1 col2
## 1    1    1
## 2    3    2
## 3    0    0
## 4    3   NA
## 5   NA    3
## 6    0    0
```

for the case of changing to zero just specific columns, you can reference those columns by index or name inside the brackets. E.g.

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c(1, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA), col2=c(1, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA), col3=rep(1, 6))
df[is.na(df$col1) & is.na(df$col2), c("col1", "col2")] <- 0
df
##   col1 col2 col3
## 1    1    1    1
## 2    3    2    1
## 3    0    0    1
## 4    3   NA    1
## 5   NA    3    1
## 6    0    0    1
```

Comment: Thank you! Almost there - one more question. This is currently changing the entire row to 0 (I have 5 columns in the dataset). How would I specify that I would like only col1 and col2 to change to 0?

Comment: You can reference the columns you want in the `[ , ]` . I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you for helping a beginner out!

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer if it solved your question and/or upvote any answers you found helpful.